# Python pandas df rename index using regex

Tags: python, pandas

My df looks like this.

```
                 2019   2018
Sally#16#       -6461  -6340
Brian#06#        7139   7200
rebecca#9#       1337   1067
mark#10#        10922  11128
toto            12936  13054
```

Here, I would like to remove #number# from all my indexes. Is there a way to achieve this? probably with regex, so that I can have a final df like this:

```
                 2019   2018
Sally           -6461  -6340
Brian            7139   7200
rebecca          1337   1067
mark            10922  11128
toto            12936  13054
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with `\d+` for select all numbers between `#`:

```
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'(#\d+#)', '')
print (df)
          2019   2018
Sally    -6461  -6340
Brian     7139   7200
rebecca   1337   1067
mark     10922  11128
toto     12936  13054
```